# Is it possible to apply multiple plugins like "android-library" and "android-reporting"

Tags: android, gradle

Am trying to create a unit test report for android subprojects and I want to merge all the reports in the same file with the command "mergeAndroidReports".

When I try to add the plugin needed which is "android-reporting", I get the following exception : 
Cannot add extension with name 'android', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

Am already using the plugin "android-library". Is there a way to use them both ?

Cheers, 
Z

Answer (score 3):

The 'android-reporting' plugin should only be applied to the root project of your mulit-project build, which itself should not have any other plugins applied. Reference the [android documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-projects-reports) for details.

> This should be applied to the root project, ie in build.gradle next to settings.gradle